# C# - Request Json File with authorization key (cURL example)

Tags: c#, json, curl, http-headers, httprequest

I'm trying to do a HTTP GET request for a json file from an api in a C# application. I'm having trouble getting the authorization, request headers and the webresponse (.GetResponse  not working).

The example on the api's site is in curl.

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN" https://erikberg.com/nba/boxscore/20120621-oklahoma-city-thunder-at-miami-heat.json
```

Here is my request method, which will also include JSON deseralization

```
public static string HttpGet(string URI)
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(URI);
    // Not sure if the credentials input is the correct
    string cred = $"{"Bearer"} {"ACCESS_TOKEN_IS_A_GUID"}";
    req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = cred;
    req.Method = "GET";

    // GetResponse() is "red", won't work.
    WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
        return reader.ReadToEnd().Trim();
    }
}
```

**EDIT** It was resolved. The problem was that the request was for a GZIP file and that had to be decompressed

```
 var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(requestUri);

        request.UserAgent = userAgent;
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = bearer; 
        request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding] = "gzip";

        var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

        string jsonString;
        using (var decompress = new GZipStream(response.GetResponseStream(), CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(decompress))
                jsonString = sr.ReadToEnd().Trim();
        }
        _Game = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Game>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting it because you don't have access.

The cURL command from API's site(that you mentioned in your question) gives the following JSON

```
  {
       "error" : {
       "code" : "401",
       "description" : "Invalid access token: ACCESS_TOKEN"
        }
  }
```

And so does the following code:

```
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("URL");
        req.UserAgent = "Bearer";
        WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
```

So what you need is a valid username/password or userAgent. You might want to contact the site for that.

Comment: Please mark it as answer if this answers your question.

Comment: I have a access token it's a guid. I will try with req.UserAgent, but I'm having problems with req.GetResponse() not existing in the context.

Comment: This got resolved for you? Are you able to execute cURL command correctly?